# Get Flex TextInput.text from dynamically created TextInput field

Tags: apache-flex

I am creating several TextInput boxes via a for loop similar to the one below. The NumberOfSelections variable will differ depending on input from the user.

```
    for(var i:int=1; i <= NumberOfSelections; i++){
            InputField = new TextInput;
            InputField.id = "Name" + i
            InputField.text = "2" 
            HGroup1.addElement(InputField);
    }
```

The TextInput text is editable when run, and the user will put in numbers and then press a calculate button that will call a new function. How do I get the information from all the TextInput fields.  For instance, if NumberOfSelections was 4 how would I get all 4 numbers the user entered in order to add them together. Is it possible to use the unique id name

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must save a reference to the fields as you create them.  I would suggest storing them in an array:

```
// somewhere in your code; define the variable
public var textBoxArray : Array = new Array();

// somewhere in some method create the textBoxes
for(var i:int=1; i <= NumberOfSelections; i++){
        InputField = new TextInput;
        InputField.id = "Name" + i
        InputField.text = "2" 
        HGroup1.addElement(InputField);
        textBoxArray.push(InputField);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flextra's answer is definitly correct. I would just like to add two other options:

**Loop over the HGroup's children**

```
for (var i:i=0; i<hGroup1.numElements; i++) {
    var inputField:TextInput = hGroup1.getElementAt(i) as TextInput;
    if (inputField) doSomthingWith(inputField.text);    
}
```

Note that from a "best practices" point of view, this isn't a very pretty approach.
A somewhat nicer approach might be to

**Ditch the dynamic instantiation and use a DataGroup instead**

Because this is exactly what a DataGroup is meant to do.

```
<s:DataGroup dataProvider="{dp}">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
                <s:TextInput text="@{data.myValue}"/>
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
</s:DataGroup>
```

Note that the `myValue` property must be declared bindable for this to work.
You can now simply loop over the items in `dp` to do your calculations and let the framework handle the dynamic instantiation. If you need to add/remove a TextInput, just add/remove an item to `dp`. In my opinion this is by far the cleanest solution, because it nicely separates your view from your model.

Comment: This won't naturally give access to user edits--you could probably grab the itemRenderer directly and ask, but it won't be reflected in the dataProvider.  One option would be to convert this example to a `DataGrid` instead.

Comment: @MichaelBrewer-Davis Yes it would. Just run the code for yourself.

Comment: @RIAstar: My apologies.  Your edit helps.  I did try running the code, but (over) simplified it to where it didn't work (using a String as `@data` directly, rather than object w/ a String property).

Answer (score 0):

use [] to reference to yours inputs:

```
for(var i:int=1; i <= NumberOfSelections; i++){
    someVariable = this["Name" + i].text;
}
```